# Windows 10: Métodos de entrada no deseados sin posibilidad de eliminarlos

Tags: windows10, configuración, idioma

Instalé Windows 10 Home Edition. Seleccioné el idioma normalmente (español Argentina) pero al tiempo de usar el equipo, en la barra de idiomas me aparecen varios métodos de entrada que no necesito. Sin embargo, al ir a eliminarlos en la configuración, sólo me aparece un método de entrada.

Cómo puedo eliminar los que no necesito? Sólo quiero teclado latinoamericano y teclado inglés.

[image: Métodos de entrada]

[image: Configuración de idioma]

[image: Teclados disponibles]

Comment: Y si vas al panel de control/region e idioma, que sale?

Comment: @NaCl lo mismo, idioma Español Argentina y teclado Estados Unidos.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es sobre programación

Answer (score 1):

He tenido el mismo problema que tú, y mi solución fue agregar esos mismos métodos de entrada y volver a borrarlos. Solo así desaparecen, es un bug de la última actualización.

Comment: Voy a probar lo que comentas, luego cuento que tal fue.